# What's wrong with this HTTP POST request?

Tags: http, http-headers, request, json

I'm trying to fuzz a server using the Sulley fuzzing framework.

I observe the following stream in Wireshark.
The error talks about a problem with JSON parsing, however, when I try the same HTTP POST request using Google Chrome's Postman extension, it succeeds.

Can anyone please explain what could be wrong about this HTTP POST request? The JSON seems valid.

```
POST /restconf/config HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:8080
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/yang.data+json
{ "toaster:toaster" : { "toaster:toasterManufacturer" : "Geqq", "toaster:toasterModelNumber" : "asaxc", "toaster:toasterStatus" : "_." }}


HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: */*
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Sat, 07 Jun 2014 05:26:35 GMT
Connection: close

152
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<errors xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-restconf">
    <error>
        <error-type>protocol</error-type>
        <error-tag>malformed-message</error-tag>
        <error-message>Error parsing input: Root element of Json has to be Object</error-message>
    </error>
</errors>

0
```

Answer (score 3):

It was the "Content-Length" property that was missing in the header and the server thought it was mandatory, which I suppose shouldn't be mandatory?

After adding the "Content-Length" to the header, works like a charm.

Comment: RFC 2616 section 4.4 says _If a request contains a message-body and a Content-Length is not given, the server SHOULD respond with 400 (bad request) if it cannot determine the length of the message_

Answer (score 1):

Based on your message, it should be a blank line before the body of the POST Request. Can you try adding one ?

As is, it is possible the server sees this request with no body and an header like :

```
{ "toaster:toaster" : value
```

which would explain the error.

Comment: Still doesn't work. :(

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because of the "Content-Type" header. If the server is configured to accept only "application/json" then it might return this error code. Though it should return "415 Unsupported Media Type" according to [RFC2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html).

This is just a guess, but you could try changing the "Content-Type" header to "application/json".

Comment: Nope. Tried changing the "Content-Type" to "application/json". Still the same error.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you may be missing a CRLF in between your last header and the payload of your request.

i.e. you have

```
POST /restconf/config HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:8080
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/yang.data+json
{ "toaster:toaster" : { "toaster:toasterManufacturer" : "Geqq", "toaster:toasterModelNumber" : "asaxc", "toaster:toasterStatus" : "_." }}
```

and it should be

```
POST /restconf/config HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:8080
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/yang.data+json

{ "toaster:toaster" : { "toaster:toasterManufacturer" : "Geqq", "toaster:toasterModelNumber" : "asaxc", "toaster:toasterStatus" : "_." }}
```